# Hit man hired to kill a cat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story about a hitman hired to kill a (black?) cat that was hanging around the house of a pharmaceutical company executive who had used thousands of cats in experiments.

**It ended badly for the hired gun. Anyone know the story?**

Comment: More detail would really help here. When did you read this story? How old was it? Where/when was it set? How exactly did it "end badly"? You might like to read [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on writing good story-ID questions.

Comment: Also, most importantly: **was this story science fiction or fantasy?** Animal experimentation and hired killers are, unfortunately, all too real.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - In this instance it was a horror story with an uplifted (and malevolent) cat.

Answer (score 5):

This is "[Cat From Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_from_Hell)" by Stephen King, available to read online [here](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781625791207/9781625791207___4.htm)

> A professional hitman is offered $12,000 to take out an unusual
>   target—a cat. He accepts, despite being told that the cat was
>   implicated in the murders of three different people. He soon discovers
>   that the cat is much more than it seems—the employer reveals that his
>   company tortured and destroyed thousands of cats in the name of
>   research, and he believes this cat is a feline emissary of revenge.
>   While the hitman is driving toward a desolate place to kill it, the
>   cat escapes confinement and eventually attacks him—crawling inside his
>   body to finish the job—after he is temporarily paralyzed in the
>   resulting accident. After killing the hitman, the cat leaves on
>   "unfinished business" to go after the hitman's employer.

You might be interested to know that it was adapted for the [Tales from the Darkside movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside:_The_Movie#Cat_from_Hell).

**Warning: NSFW (Slightly Gory)**

Comment: Wow. So fast, and with so little detail in the question. You have powers.

Comment: I was watching this a few months ago. It just chimed

Comment: [The Cat From Hell](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781625791207/9781625791207___4.htm), Baen Books.

Comment: @user1155120 - Cheers for the link.